# action button not visible in android notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to customize android notification like this.

[image]

Everything works fine for Above API23. For below API23 action button is not visible. I don't find what's wrong with my code.

**here is my sample code** for below API23:

```
RemoteViews expandedView = createMultiRemoteViews(context,
                R.layout.notification_multiview_b23, icon, "Custom notification", "This is a custom layout", leftImage, rightImage, "09:10", "16:23");

expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_image, leftImageIntent);
expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_image, rightImageIntent);

NotificationCompat.Action addToWatchListAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp,
                LABEL_ADD_TO_WATCH_LIST, addToWatchList).build();

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = createNotificationBuider(context, "Custom notification", "This is a custom layout", icon);
builder.addAction(addToWatchListAction);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);

showNotification(context, builder.build(), MULTI_NOTI_ID);
```

Comment: which android version have you tried? [NotificationCompat.Action official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action.html) says it won't work prior to Android 4.1

Comment: @rala i tried for Android version 6.0.1
my minSDK version is 16.

Answer (score 0):

Notification Actions aren't available below API 24. It might be a compatibility issue. To support backward compatibility, use the support library's NotificationComapt class.
Here's [a link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to official documentation and [a link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action.html) link to support library class.

Comment: I used NotificationCompact class.

Comment: @khaleel_jageer
"Not all notification features are available for a particular version, even though the methods to set them are in the support library class NotificationCompat.Builder. For example, action buttons, which depend on expanded notifications, only appear on Android 4.1 and higher, because expanded notifications themselves are only available on Android 4.1 and higher."
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Compatibility